# I don't understand why my python code is showing warning?

Tags: python

I am learning coding in Python. I am facing an issue today. My code is showing output correctly but it is showing a warning. I don't know where is the fault. Please help me to solve it.

Code:

```
class Info:
    Name = ""
    Roll = ""
    Section = ""
    Department = ""
    Session = ""
    University = ""


def display(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    print(f"Name: {a}")
    print(f"ID: {b}")
    print(f"Section: {c}")
    print(f"Department: {d}")
    print(f"Session: {e}")
    print(f"University: {f}")


Code = input("Enter Code: ")
Code = Info()  # Error in this line
Code.Name = input("Enter Name: ")
Code.Roll = input("Enter ID: ")
Code.Section = input("Enter Section Name: ")
Code.Department = input("Enter Department Name: ")
Code.Session = input("Enter Session: ")
Code.University = input("Enter University Name: ")
display(Code.Name, Code.Roll, Code.Section, Code.Department, Code.Session, Code.University)
```

Error is showing in this line `Code = Info()`

Error message:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `Code = input("Enter Code: ")` what is the purpose of this line u are not storing it anywhere and Code is replacing with the instance of info() in the next line. Use `print("display message")` if you just want to just show some message.

Comment: In other words, you’re never doing anything with `Code = input("Enter Code: ")`; either you want to remove it because it’s useless, or you forgot to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The warning message from your IDE's linter tells you:

`Redeclared "Code" defined above without usage.`

`Code` is defined by your `input()` function call.  But then you define `Code` again immediately by calling `Info()`, without ever using the result of calling `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are reassigning the same variable (Code) on 2 consecutive lines.

You Can remove first line

Code = input....

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is showing up because you define a variable called `Code` in which you store the input on this line:

```
Code = input("Enter Code: ")
```

but then you never actually use it, since you redefine it in the next line:

```
Code = Info()
```

As you noticed this may not cause any errors, but many modern code editors warn you about unused variables. In your case you should ask yourself what is the purpose of the user input and why aren't you using it anywhere?